# how does it come that atmospheric pressure does not cut off blood flow in blood vessels?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

We know that atmospheric pressure is 760mmHg, whereas blood pressure in blood vessels is somewhere between 80 to 120 mmHg. As outer pressure is higher than inner so shouldn't it cut off the blood flow?

Comment: Those pressure values for blood vessels are so-called gauge pressures (i.e., relative to atmospheric).  Gauge pressure is absolute pressure minus atmospheric pressure.  So the absolute pressures in the blood vessels actually do exceed atmospheric pressure.

Comment: I am sure that the blood pressure value is the excess pressure not the total pressure.

Comment: @ChesterMiller I think your comment qualifies as an answer

Comment: A sphygmomanometer measures the blood pressure gauge.